# Why Windows 8 would display colored squares instead of icons in the Search charm?

Tags: windows-8, search, icons, windows-store-app, charms-bar

If I try to search anything, I only see colored squares instead of app icons, but only for Windows Store Apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the 'Turn off the display of thumbnails and only display icons on network folders' setting that lives in 'Local Computer Policy Editor/User Configuration/Administrative Templates/Windows Components/File Explorer'. If the setting is Enabled, then you won't see Windows Store App icons.

I guess it has something to do with sand-boxing? Maybe they store Windows Store Apps in some sort of virtual network drive?

Comment: Or just get them straight from internet

Comment: I don't quite get what you've said...the problem this solves is related to Group Policy only, nothing to do with the internet...